# Feedparser, no etag and modified attributes

Tags: python, rss, feed, feedparser

How could I know if the feed has changed since last check if none of these attributes exists for a given feed ?
Example with this one from a nintendo news website:

```
d=feedparser.parse('https://www.nintendolife.com/feeds/news')

[In]:'modified' in d 
[Out]:False

[In]:'etag' in d 
[Out]:False
```

Is my only possibility to check d.feed.published / d.feed.updated ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky and the problem is that sometimes you won't know.

The 'etag' and 'modified' variables are not required and often not used.  The 'updated' and 'published' variables are not meant to be used for this so your mileage may vary.  In any event some publishers use 'published' and 'updated' as a timestamp that changes on each request.  This even happens with some of the most well known news outlets.

While the standards have been created and defined they are not always implemented in the way prescribed.  As is the case for any data, you can use hashing to check for changes so this could be an option.

Whatever you choose it means that you will need to analyse feeds on a case by case basis for what indicates an update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've finished this project a while ago and that's how i've done it, etag/modified when available and hash when not